# How to remove a confluent-hub installed package?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

How to remove a confluent-hub installed package?

```
rm -rf /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/module* ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remove the connector files as well as restart each Kafka Connect worker where it was installed, yes.